# How to pass bash variable to cmd?

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file

how can I pass `$line` to the `cmd` command?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line           
do           
    sshpass -p "..." ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt windows@172....-p 333  cmd /c "cd C:\ & download_give_id.exe '$@$line' "

done <apps.txt
```

Comment: Could it be that just the single quotes '$@$line' prevent variable  expansion?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you want to interpolate a variable into a bash string you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
str="${var} foo bar" # works
str='${var} for bar' # works not
```

In the special case that you are running ssh commands inside a while loop, I strongly recommend to pass `/dev/tty` explicitly as input to the command since once the remote command should read from stdin - for whatever reason - it will slurp stdin of the while loop otherwise:

```
while read line ; do
    ssh ... -- "${line} ..."  < /dev/tty # Pass tty to stdin
done < input.txt
```

Note: The above command will work only if the process has been started in a terminal. If the process is not running in a terminal, you need to pass something else as stdin for the inner ssh command.